# Deleting a Wordpress install on AWS

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, bitnami

I installed wordpress with bitnami on amazon aws EC2. But there are some errors with it and I want to start afresh. But I can't seem to remove the one I installed. I installed another one using the same wordpress market place and it just created another public ip on that same instance.

Comment: How did you try to remove the 1st instance and what happened?

Comment: I just launched another instance thinking it would overwrite this current one. I was wrong, It just created another ec2 instance

Comment: When you’re done with an EC2 instance, you need to terminate it. Please also read https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-lifecycle.html

Comment: Can't I just like reset a wordpress instalation on the same instance?

Comment: Sure, if you know how to do that, but you originally said you wanted to start afresh.